# How to freez an element after drop in container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some elements which are `draggable`.

you can check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Neha_Maniyar/SRPm2/18/)

I want to freeze these elements after dropping into particular container.
you can say that i have to drop one element into one block, it cannot be dropped to other blocks.

Comment: Upon drop event, set draggable to disabled true and you will no longer be able to drag it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
$(ui.draggable).draggable({ disabled: true });
```

it disables `draggable` element on `handleDropEvent`

```
function handleDropEvent (event, ui) {
   $(ui.draggable).draggable({ disabled: true });
}
```

Documentation is available [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/)

Working [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/SRPm2/21/)

Comment: this is not really i want . i want perticular element to be placed at perticular position and freez that element only freez when that element would be place at that perticular place and then get id of that element in alert box and freez that place.

Comment: This is not that really what i want, i want to freez the perticular container when perticular element will be dropped at that container only and freez that perticular container and print the id of element in alert box.

Comment: you can get the id of element, for eg: $(ui.draggable).draggable()[0].id. Then do your checks.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not good with javascript but this fiddle at `*http://jsfiddle.net/QqJRs/*` may help.

i haven't looked into it, but some event changes red box to green after it is dropped, work that out and i am sure you will get your answer

good luck